# How to convert te JSON string to a JSON object in php?

Tags: php, json

I got a object like this:
`{"1":"FFS","2":"S"}`, and I use `json_decode` function to convert it into an array, but I am not success with it. It becomes the array like this: {"FFS", "S"}, but missing the {"1", "2"}, Can I convert it to become a dict or something, that I can access both value? Thanks.

Comment: use true as second parameter to retrieve an associative array

Comment: `print_r( json_decode('{"1":"FFS","2":"S"}', true) );`

Comment: The title states you want an object, yet you ask for an array.

Answer (score 3):

use `true` param, to convert object to associative array for [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), like do:

```
$str = '{"1":"FFS","2":"S"}';
echo "<pre>"; print_r(json_decode($str, true));
```

gives::

```
Array
(
    [1] => FFS
    [2] => S
)
```

Comment: Deleted my answer since they were almost the same. +1 anyway! :)

Comment: @Ted Wong: please note that I had the same answer but 1 minute earlier.

Comment: Because - see my comment in that. Despite question title OP clarified desired result quite well in question itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myjsonobject = json_decode('{"1":"FFS","2":"S"}');
```

Should working.
Try: `print_r($myjsonobject);` to validate.

Its working.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This will not do the stuff.

Comment: I tested it. Working. AND: its not an array like you said (quote: "I use json_decode function to convert it into an array") - its an object. You can see it in the output (screenshot).

Comment: it's **not** working since OP want result as _an array_ while your code returns _object_ (see your output).

Comment: **Please read the post title**! "How to convert te JSON string to a JSON **object** in php?"